# How do I make a rectangular plot with annotations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pstricks

I want to plot the following

[image]

But I am unable to add the details(the C's with their pointing segment) and unable to keep the $x$-axis shorter than $y$-axis as shown in the diagram. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,kpfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{
  calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns,
  decorations.pathreplacing % <- added
}
\tikzset{
point/.style={circle,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt}
}
\pgfplotsset{
    soldot/.style={color=blue,only marks,mark=*}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xmax=1.5,
            xmin=-1.5,
            axis equal,
            xtick={0},
            ytick={-2,-1,1,2},
            axis lines =middle, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}
          ]
          \addplot [blue, smooth,domain=-2:2] {x^3+2};
          \addplot [blue, smooth,domain=-2:2] {x^3+1};
          \addplot [blue, smooth,domain=-2:2] {x^3};
          \addplot [blue, smooth,domain=-2:2] {x^3-1};
          \addplot [thick, red, smooth,domain=-2:2] {x^3-2};
          \addplot[soldot,red]coordinates {(1,-1)} node [anchor=west,text=black]  {$(1,-1)$};
          \node at (axis cs:-0.6,-0.3) [anchor=west] {$0$}; 
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `width` and `height` to set the dimensions of the axis, adjust to your liking. For the labels, you can first add a `coordinate` at an appropriate `pos` at each `\addplot`, e.g. `\addplot {..} coordinate[pos=0.6] (foo);`, then add `clip mode=individual` to the `axis` options, and finally use `\node [pin={30:$C=x$}] at (foo) {};` to make the pin with label.

In the code below I used a loop, as the code becomes a lot shorter, but you can of course write out everything if you find it clearer.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
point/.style={circle,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt}
}
\pgfplotsset{
    soldot/.style={color=blue,only marks,mark=*}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin edge/.style={black,thin}, pin distance=7mm]
    \begin{axis}[
            % set size of axis
            width=7cm,height=10cm,
            % disable clipping of \node, \draw, etc., while keeping clipping of \addplot
            clip mode=individual,
            xmax=1.5,
            xmin=-1.5,
            axis equal,
            xtick={0},
            ytick={-2,-1,1,2},
            axis lines =middle, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}
          ]

       \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-2,...,2}{
         \ifnum #1 = -2
           \addplot [thick, red, smooth,domain=-2:2] {x^3+#1} coordinate[pos=0.68] (n#1);
         \else
           \addplot [blue, smooth,domain=-2:2] {x^3+#1} coordinate[pos=0.64-0.02*#1] (n#1);
         \fi
         \node[inner sep=1pt,pin={[anchor=west]30:$C=#1$}] at (n#1) {};
        } 
        \addplot[soldot,red]coordinates {(1,-1)} node [anchor=west,text=black]  {$(1,-1)$};
        \node at (axis cs:-0.6,-0.3) [anchor=west] {$0$}; 
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{pst-plot,multido}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-5)(3.5,5)
\psaxes[labels=y]{->}(0,0)(-2,-5)(2,5)
\multido{\iA=-2+1,\rA=1.1+0.05}{5}{%
  \psplot[linecolor=\ifnum\iA>-2 blue\else red\fi,algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt]{-1.5}{2}{x^3+\iA}%
  \psline(*\rA\space x^3+\iA)(!2 \rA\space 3 exp \iA\space add)
  \uput[0](!2 \rA\space 3 exp \iA\space add){$C=\iA$}}
  \psdot[linecolor=red,dotscale=1.5](1,-1)
  \uput[-45](1,-1){$(1,-1)$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A way to do this with MetaPost, for whom it may interest. The problematic pointing segments are build thanks to the handy `cutafter` macro. As its names suggests, it doesn't draw the part of a given path located after its intersection with another given path.

The MetaPost code is included in a LuaLaTeX program for convenience.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85, luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
picture curves; path graph[];
u := cm; xmin = -2.5; xmax = 3; xstep := .1; ymax = -ymin = 4;
beginfig(1); 
  % Axes
  drawarrow (xmin*u, 0) -- (xmax*u, 0);
  label.bot("$x$", (xmax*u, 0));
  drawarrow (0, ymin*u) -- (0, ymax*u);
  label.ulft("$y$", (0, ymax*u)); 
  % Clipped cubic curves
  curves = image(
    for C = -2 upto 2:
      graph[C] = function(2, "x", "x**3+(" & decimal C & ")", xmin, xmax, xstep) scaled u;
      draw graph[C] withcolor if C = -2: red else: blue fi;
      label.ulft("$" & decimal C & "$", (0, C*u));
    endfor;);
  clip curves to 
    unitsquare xyscaled (xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin) shifted (xmin, ymin) scaled u;
  draw curves;
  % Equation, and label for (1, 1)
  z = (u, -u); drawdot z withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;
  label.rt("$(1, -1)$", z); label.rt("$y = x^3 + C$", u*(xmin, .75ymax));
  % Labels C and their segments
  for C = -2 upto 2:
    pair loc; loc = u*(1.75+.06(C+2), 2.5+.6C);
    label.rt("$C = " & decimal C & "$", loc);
    draw (loc -- loc+infinity*dir (-165)) cutafter graph[C] ;
  endfor;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]